# How can I restore details of jewelry in old photo?

Tags: restoration, jewelry

I have an old photo that has a family vintage ring on it. The ring is blurred and its details are not visible. I have no experience with photoshop and image processing and have no clue if it's even possible to restore the image and be able to see the ring's details.

The ring is a precious gift from my grandma which was stolen a few years ago and I hoped that I can order a replica by providing a clear photo.

Can you please give some hints on where to start (tools, techniques, services..anything is helpful) ?

Thank you very much!!

[image]

Comment: I think that your best option would be to gather as many images as you can of that ring, and present them to an actual human jeweler. All the AI image fixing tools in the world still haven't gotten the leg up on an actual human interpretation.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, you cannot "restore" the details. The details are lost because of the low resolution of the photo. They're not hidden, and contrary to what popular shows like CSI portray, there's no way to enhance your way back to what was originally there.

The only thing you can do, short of digging up more photos with more detail, is to use tools like [Topaz](https://www.topazlabs.com/) to create detail artificially. The resulting image will be sharper and might even look natural and realistic, but it is still an approximation and an extrapolation from your original image in low resolution.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your experience!

Answer (score 0):

What you can try is to amplify the details which are not very prominent. Because there are no additional details you can reveal. The methods I know are:

1. convert to black and white and increase contrast. This will show the shapes of the object and make them more "visible". Here you can play with colour temperature to see if some details are more contrasty/visible.
2. you can try with pseudo solarisation to "increase" the contrast on colour level. This also can give some details, based on colour changes. Also you can convert to black and white.

And if you own the paper photo you can try to scan it with bigger depth of colours (for method 2). Also bigger resolution of scan may help.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your experience! Will try these steps